# Prompt() not working in current nodejs v20.3.1

Tags: node.js, prompt, readline

```js
const prompt = require('node:prompt-sync');
const name = prompt('What is your name?');
console.log(`Hey there ${name}`)
```

anyone have solution for the following error caused by this code.

```
PS C:\_HCJ> node Myfile.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:918
      throw new ERR_UNKNOWN_BUILTIN_MODULE(request);
      ^

Error [ERR_UNKNOWN_BUILTIN_MODULE]: No such built-in module: node:prompt-sync
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:918:13)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1139:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\_HCJ\Myfile.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1257:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1311:10)     
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:962:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_BUILTIN_MODULE'
}
```

Node.js v20.3.1

Answer (score 0):

There's no builtin called `prompt-sync`, as the error says. You want [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt-sync) most likely. The `node:` prefix is for [builtin modules](https://2ality.com/2021/12/node-protocol-imports.html) only. To fix: `npm i prompt-sync` and use `require('prompt-sync')`.